# How can I share private libraries in Dart?

Tags: dart

I've got a Dart application that consists of both client and server components. There are a couple of source files that are needed by both client and server. I'm trying to find a way to share them effectively *without* publishing a library to pub.

I've read through [these docs](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/create-library-packages) but it doesn't say how to share a library if you don't want to publish it to pub. I'd like to do something like:

```
import 'package:../../Shared/lib/shared.dart';
```

But that doesn't work ("Target of URI does not exist").

What options do I have here?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I figured it out. I have to declare a dependency in my `pubspec.yaml` like this:

```
  shared:
    path: ../shared
```

Then I can just do this:

```
import 'package:shared/shared.dart';
```